# How to find rows in Pandas dataframe where re.search fails

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to pull wind direction out of a Metar string with format:

```
EGAA 010020Z 33004KT 300V010 9999 FEW029 04/04 Q1019
```

I'm using this to extract the wind direction which works for most of my data but fails on some strings:

```
df["Wind_Dir"] = df.metar.apply(lambda x: int(re.search(r"\s\d*KT\s", metar_data.metar[0]).group().strip()[:3]))
```

I'd like to inspect the Metar strings that it's failing on so instead of pulling `group()` out of the `re.search` I just applied the search as follows to get the `re.Match` object:

```
df["Wind_Dir"] = df.metar.apply(lambda x: re.search(r"\s\d*KT\s", x))
```

I've tried filtering by type and by Null but neither of those work.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Thanks for your answers unfortunately I can't mark them both as solutions despite using both to solve my problem.

In the end I changed my regex to:

`df["Wind_Dir"] = df.metar.str.findall(r"Z\s\d\d\d|Z\sVRB")`

to match for variable direction but wouldn't have been able to find that without `df.metar.str.contains()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your code to return matched string and not an re object.

This will also not work when there is no match since re.search won't return anything.

> Try [pandas.series.str.findall](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html)

In your case try this

```
df['Wind_Dir'] = df.metar.str.findall(r"\s\d*KT\s")
df["Wind_Dir"] = df['Wind_Dir'].apply(lambda x: x[0].strip()[:3])
```

You also might want to check whether there is a match or not before executing 2nd statement.

Answer (score 4):

You are searching for this:
[pandas.Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains) returns a mask with True for indexes that match the pattern based on `re.search`.

As Pandas documentation states, if you want a mask based on `re.match` you should use: [pandas.Series.str.match](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html).

You can also use the following:
[pandas.Series.str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) which extracts the first match of the pattern on every rows of the Series on which you perform the analysis. `NaN` will fill the rows that didn't contain the pattern so you can fetch for `Nan` values to retrieve such rows.